# Terminal syntax corection

Tags: for-loop, terminal, automation, youtube, command

Following command is for uploading video on YouTube.

```bash
python upload_video.py --file="/Users/Justin/Desktop/1.mp4"
                       --title="Summer vacation in California"
                       --description="Had fun surfing in Santa Cruz"
                       --keywords="surfing,Santa Cruz"
                       --category="22"
                       --privacyStatus="private"
```

Im trying to make this for more videos at once. Reason why Im sucked is because every time I tried to make a program in .command file, output is: `" Please specify a valid file using the --file= parameter."`

```bash
source ~/env/YTapi/bin/activate
for i in {1..50}; do
    echo $i
    python upload_video.py --file="
/Volumes/1T/youtube shorts/Relationships 50 videos/{$i}.mp4" --title="" --description="" --keywords="" --category="" --privacyStatus="public"
done
```

Reason why Im stuck is because I don't know how to do valid parameter in loop. Every time I tried to go to do it on its own (separately) the path of the folders was valid. I was also trying to check if my syntax is correct of this program.

I'll be glad for any help provided here.  Thank you.